# Where to put dependencies for scala

Tags: scala, classpath

I'm getting this compile error:

```
owner@PC ~/scala/fxml: scalac x.scala
x.scala:1: error: object asynchttpclient is not a member of package org
import org.asynchttpclient.*;
           ^
one error found
```

I figured I needed to download the .java files for org.asynchttpclient.* so I copied those to `c:\classes` and set `CLASS_PATH` to `c:\classes` but that didn't work.

Note: I know about sbt and maven but I just want to get scalac working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is with the dependency for x.scala. You need to download the asynchttpclient jar if you don't have it. Then apply the following command to include it in compilation.

```
scalac -classpath "asynchttpclient.jar:other dependent jars" x.scala
```

Comment: OK so I set CLASSPATH to the .jar file, and I get the jarfile by compiling [the repo](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client) somehow?

Comment: I didn't understand your comment. please clarify

Comment: I'm asking how do I get the .jar file. Right now I have a bunch of .java files in folders starting with org/asynchttpclient/...

Comment: please look at [creating executable jars](http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/createjar.html)

Comment: Hmm, it sounds like I should stick with sbt, yes?

Comment: look at [package with sbt](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/sbt-how-to-compile-run-package-scala-project) for sbt.

Comment: @pguardiario Yes, you should.

Answer (score 1):

It's `CLASSPATH`, not `CLASS_PATH`. You can also use `-classpath ...` as an option to `scalac`.